# Language settings in Justboil.me

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, justboil.me

I've set up the Justboil.me plugin to TinyMCE 4. It works great, but I can't make the language files work correctly.
TinyMCE is set to Hungarian.
I've created *hu_HU_dlg.js* and *hu_HU.js*. No luck so far.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this plugin's language functions are designed for TinyMCE 3.x.
I managed to solve the problem by adding the translation to TinyMCE's language file instead of the plugin's language file. Now it works perfectly.